# Polymer 2.x paper-radio-group selectedValues not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, paper-elements

I am trying to work with the selectedValues property of a paper-radio-group (using the multi option). According to documentation, this property should be a setter and a getter to the selected radio buttons. But it does not seem to work.

[image]

I have made a plunker to test it: https://embed.plnkr.co/6YK15vgv33IX2ZqYHmpQ/

As you can see the red and white should be selected. But they don't. Also when you start selecting items, the selectedValues is never fired.

```
<paper-radio-group multi selectedValues="[0,3]">
      <paper-radio-button>Red</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button>Green</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button>Blue</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button>White</paper-radio-button>
      <paper-radio-button>Purple</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding of `selectedValues` needs to be dash-cased (`selected-values`)):

```
<paper-radio-group selected-values="[0,3]">
```

And the `<paper-radio-button>`s need their `name` attributes set to match the selected values:

```
<paper-radio-button name="0">Red</paper-radio-button>
<paper-radio-button name="1">Green</paper-radio-button>
<paper-radio-button name="2">Blue</paper-radio-button>
<paper-radio-button name="3">White</paper-radio-button>
<paper-radio-button name="4">Purple</paper-radio-button>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RVPTnsLXjwlA7j6RVww1?p=preview)

Comment: I started playing around with this solution demo, but whenever you add a name to the <paper-radio-button> the multi select gets all messed up. If I delete the names, multi select starts working just fine.

Comment: Digging deeper, this is a bug that already has a pull request since 2016. A one liner, that seems to work! https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group/pull/71/files